# Is there way to find type casts in Python code

Tags: python, numpy, casting

I found that mixing different types can lead to a significant slowdown.
For instance, a mix of `numpy.int` and generic Python `int` may cause a 20 times slowdown in some cases.

```
import numpy
import random
from timeit import timeit

N = 10000

python_ints_in = [random.randint(50, 100) for _ in range(N)]  
python_ints_out = [random.randint(50, 100) for _ in range(N)]
numpy_ints_out = numpy.array(python_ints_out, dtype=numpy.intc)

test_set = set(python_ints_in)

def pyt():
    return sum(i in test_set for i in python_ints_out)

def num():
    return sum(i in test_set for i in numpy_ints_out)

print(timeit(pyt, number=1000))  # 0.45s
print(timeit(num, number=1000))  # 11.3s
```

I want to track down type casting in some big projects to see if it is possible to choose more consistent types to improve performance.

---

**Profiling**

Of course, I did it, and it is how I discovered this issue. It is maybe not exactly typecasting, but something around it. Anyway, type mixing is a bottleneck. The `set` was the simplest way for me to reproduce this bottleneck separately. In my project, it happens with `dict`, multiplication, and maybe other operations, which I want to track. By profiling, I found a couple of places that led totally to two times slowing in the whole run. I fixed them by correcting types, but left 10% slowdown is not acceptable.

---

**Arithmetic example**

```
import numpy
import dis
from timeit import timeit

a_int = 123
b_int = 178

a_intc = numpy.intc(a_int)
b_intc = numpy.intc(b_int)
print(type(b_intc))  # <class 'numpy.int32'>
print(type(b_int))   # <class 'int'>

def pyt():
    return a_int//b_int

def mix():
    return a_int//b_intc

def num():
    return a_intc//b_intc

print(timeit(pyt, number=1000000))  # 0.056
print(timeit(mix, number=1000000))  # 1.382
print(timeit(num, number=1000000))  # 0.101
```

The disassembled code differs only by used types.

```
# pyt
 14           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_int)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_int)
              4 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
              6 RETURN_VALUE
# mix
 17           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_int)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_intc)
              4 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
              6 RETURN_VALUE
# num
 20           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a_intc)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b_intc)
              4 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Unrelated to casting, you want to *profile* your code. If casting isn't a bottleneck, you don't care about how slow it is. Find the bottlenecks, and fix them, regardless of the cause.

Comment: For me the times were 0.7s and 2.7s, much less difference. Also, you are comparing a `list` and a `numpy array`, you are not comparing identical behavior, meaning the difference doesn't have to be because of the cast

Comment: For instance, using `numpy.vectorize` the speed was more than doubled in my machine (and I did a pretty crappy implementation). I am pretty sure that code quality in general has more impact than the types.

Comment: And just for reference, using `np.isin(numpy_ints_out,np.array([x for x in test_set])).sum()` it takes 0.4s vs 0.71s of your pyt implementation

Comment: Your `num` is using a numpy  array in a list-like manner.  That kind of iteration is slow.  To get good speed with arrays, you should use compiled array methods.  If you must iterate, it is better to stick with lists.  It isn't a matter of "casting", but rather misuse of arrays.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your results in the debian environment. However, this is not caused by "type casts". If you cast manually like `int(i)` , the difference becomes smaller. It seems that this is caused by python's implementation of `set.__contains__` . Generally speaking, you cannot detect type casts in python. Instead, you can cast yourself into the type you want.

Comment: @ken, thanks for your idea, the problem that I also have slowdown in operations like `int*intc`. I will check if explicit type casting help in other places.

Comment: But how do you qualify "slowdown on int*intc" vs "int*int". How can you state that the slowdown comes from the heterogeneous type and not from the instructions that you are using?

Comment: @ZaeroDivide , I added an example with division. I state because I do not see any other difference in the code. The instructions are completely the same in the second case. There is some difference between `intc//intc` and `int/int` but it is not so dramatic as difference between `int/intc` with any of above.

Comment: There is no "casting" going on. It really isnt clear what you expect to "track down" precisely. But yes, mixing `numpy` with standard numeric types is going to take longer

Comment: @hpaulj, in the second example, that I added there is no lists, arrays or iterations. There are just plan values and division. And you may be right that numpy itself is a bit slower, but not so bad as when I mixed types.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, actually mixing `numpy.int32` with `numpy.int64` also leads to a similar issue. I want to track down where python does operations on different types.

Comment: For fun, `return a_intc//b_int` is even slower in my machine. And the cost of casting is nil (`return int(a_intc)//b_int` takes the same as `return a_int//b_int`

Comment: But again, I am not sure this is representative. We are talking about 1M operation of heterogeneous types. I don't think pure numpy is 2-4x slower on heterogeneous type. (note that my worst slowdown is only 4x, not 20x)

Comment: I have 2M+ calls in the runtime in a test scenario and much more in real runs. I would say python is not very suitable for such computations, but it is not what I can easily change at the moment.

Comment: If you are doing many calls using primitive types, I would suggest to check Cython and cdef functions, as calling overhead is much lower. Also they could be parallelized with openMP.

Comment: Stoll if you are doing a lot of scalar math with elements of an array, you are misusing arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj, there is no essential usage of arrays in these examples. The `ndarray` needs me in another part of the code, where it actually gives some improvement. The problem that I faced that changing code to `ndarray` in one part, I lost time in the part that I did not touch, but scalars extracted from `ndarray` far up the call stack got a different type. I expected that scalars are handled more or less with the same speed even if they have mixed types. But it appears wrong assumption.

Comment: By using [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/) in combination with numpy this kind of code can be sped up considerably.

Comment: You can use `item` and `tolist` to get base python objects from numpy arrays and scalars.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks, I thought that `tuple(a.flatten())` and `tuple(a.flatten().tolist()))`  would give the same results but it turned out that types are different.  

@JanChristophTerasa, yes, thanks for info about numba, I checked and it gave notable speed up on some tests, yet using in-depth of the project may require a leap of logic to numba-ize classes. 

@ZaeroDivide, at first glance, with Cython I was able to speed up only pure Python code, it didn’t give any notable changes for code with NumPy. But thanks anyway. I will recheck if I can use it more efficiently.

Comment: Numba in general is much easier to apply than Cython. For the latter, use "annotated output" and make that there is no "yellow" in the output, specially in the inner loops. Cython shines when using C primitives, C functions and memoryviews. Also implementing "pure C" functions as calls are much faster than python counterparts. But doing something like this is quite tedious, and often overkill.